# Call to "admin_notices" hook from a static method

Tags: php, plugin-development, oop

Trying to call "admin_notices" hook from a static function. Getting no output. While normal calling to the same hook is working.

```php
use Awraq\Init;
use Awraq\Notice;

/**
 * Initialize the activation works of the plugin.
 */
function awraq_activate_plugin()
{

    /* NOT WORKING */
    Notice::error('Activation failed');

    
    /* WORKING */

    //add_action('admin_notices', 'simplefunction');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'awraq_activate_plugin');



function simplefunction()
{
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
        <p>Activation failed</p></div>';
}
```

**class**

```php
namespace Awraq;

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

class Notice
{
    private static $class = '';
    private static $msg = '';

    public static function error($msg = 'error', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-error is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-error';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function warning($msg = 'warning', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-warning is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-warning';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function success($msg = 'success', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-success is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-success';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function info($msg = 'info', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-info is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-info';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function  awraq_notice()
    {

        $class  = self::$class;
        $msg    = self::$msg;

        if ($class == '' and $msg == '') {
            return;
        }

        printf('<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr($class), esc_html($msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is static but you're setting properties on it that you want to persist when a static method is called later. That's not how static classes or methods work.

Comment: Hi, there are no issue regarding accessing properties or methods in my context.  Just tested. 
Removed the first occurrence of add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__, 'awraq_notice')); in "error" method and then calling the self::awraq_notice(). Getting the desired output. I'm suspecting, it might related to timing related thing. 

Thanks

Comment: `add_action('admin_notices', array(CLASS, 'awraq_notice'))` is not the same thing as calling `self::awraq_notice()`. Use `call_user_func( array( __CLASS__, 'awraq_notice' );` and you'll get the same result. This approach isn't going to work.

Comment: @PijushGupta see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/#process-flow) if for example you wish to display a notice right after your plugin is activated..

Answer (score 0):

Issue got solved by doing two things

- Removed primary calling from

```
/**
 * Initialize the activation works of the plugin.
 */
function awraq_activate_plugin()
{
    //removed 
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'awraq_activate_plugin');
```

Added the call to "plugins_loaded"

```
/**
 * Initialize the plugin.
 */
function awraq_init_plugin()
{
    if (Init::activate() != TRUE) {
        deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
        //added below
        Notice::error('Plugin got Deactivated. Please check the dependencies.', true);
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'awraq_init_plugin');
```

- And on the class removed `__CLASS__` with full namespace and class - `private static $globalScopeName = 'Awraq\Base\Notice';`, since it will get called from outside of this.

```
namespace Awraq\Base;

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

class Notice
{
    private static $globalScopeName = 'Awraq\Base\Notice';
    private static $class = '';
    private static $msg = '';

    public static function error($msg = 'error', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-error is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-error';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(self::$globalScopeName, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function warning($msg = 'warning', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-warning is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-warning';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(self::$globalScopeName, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function success($msg = 'success', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-success is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-success';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(self::$globalScopeName, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function info($msg = 'info', $is_dismissible = TRUE)
    {
        self::$class = ($is_dismissible == TRUE) ? 'notice notice-info is-dismissible' : 'notice notice-info';
        self::$msg = __($msg, AWRAQ_TEXT_DOMAIN);
        add_action('admin_notices', array(self::$globalScopeName, 'awraq_notice'));
    }

    public static function  awraq_notice()
    {

        $class  = self::$class;
        $msg    = self::$msg;

        if ($class == '' and $msg == '') {
            return;
        }

        printf('<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr($class), esc_html($msg));
    }
}
```